# Wordpress: WP_List_Table number of all items

Tags: wordpress, numbers, items

Hi I'm edditing code on edit-coments.php file and I want to get number of all items (comments).

If I use **count($wp_list_table->items)** it only returns number of items showed on thatpage. How to get number of all comments (items)?

Comment: Where are you trying to display this info? In the site front-end or the back-end admin screen?
Also note that it is not a good practice to hack the core WordPress files.

Comment: the problem is that pagination is somehow broken, and $wp_list_table->_pagination_args['total_items'] returns null. So I want to set it (set_pagination_args) manualy

Answer (score 0):

The total items count is in the pagination args array:

```
$wp_list_table->_pagination_args['total_items'];
```

Please note that, as pointed out in the comments, editing/hacking core WP files is strongly discouraged. Future WordPress updates will mercilessly overwrite your edits.